# Netlogo count links with

Tags: count, range, netlogo

I have a own breed computer and I want to count all computers within a range which are online. Following didn't worked because "on" is not able in link context how is it done right?

```
let cnt count link-neighbors with [link-length <= range and online = 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this.

This one is probably the simplest. Remember that `link-neighbors` returns the computers that the current computer is linked to, not the links themselves. So we can just look at the neighboring computers in range as follows:

```
count link-neighbors in-radius range with [online = 1]
```

Alternatively, you could look at the links themselves and use [`other-end`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other-end) to figure out if the connected computer is online:

```
count my-links with [link-length <= range and [online = 1] of other-end]
```

The advantage of this method is that you could use something besides actual physical distance as the range. For instance, if the links had a `latency` variable that was the time it took for messages to go across them, you could do:

```
count my-links with [latency <= max-latency and [online = 1] of other-end]
```

Comment: I love it when someone finds a use for `other-end`.